# Find Cause of Heroku H10 Error Using Sentry in Flask

Tags: docker, heroku, flask, sentry

I am building a Flask-based app for deployment to Heroku using a Docker container. While I can run the application inside of the Docker container and can start it using the console on my Heroku dashboard, when I release it, it crashes with an H10 "app crashed" error.

In an attempt to find the cause, I provisioned the Sentry addon and followed the instructions to install it. I had gotten a couple of error messages reported through Sentry, but now it's not reporting anything (I think the previous ones might have come from an interactive Docker session). I've been looking over any documentation that might help, but I haven't been able to find anything that helps.

Here are the contents of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
COPY . /hyena
WORKDIR /hyena/
RUN apt update
RUN apt install --ignore-missing -y git mscore xmlstarlet python3.7 python3-distutils python3-pip curl
RUN curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install --upgrade 'sentry-sdk[flask]==0.7.8'
RUN git clone https://github.com/icwells/unixpath.git && cd unixpath && python3 setup.py install && cd ../ && rm -rf unixpath

ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
EXPOSE 8000
```

And my heroku.yml (gunicorn is in my requirements.txt file):

```
setup:
  addons:
  - plan: sentry-clean-70182

build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile

run:
  web: gunicorn -w 3 -k gthread "hyena:create_app()"
```

And relevant lines from **init**.py:

```py
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.flask import FlaskIntegration

sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn="...", # Actual dsn in file
    integrations=[FlaskIntegration()]
)
```

If I could see the errors being generated within the dyno, I could probably figure this out in a couple of minutes, but as of right now I have no idea what they are. If anyone can identify any errors I might have with my Sentry configuration here (or Heroku), that would be amazing.

I'm certainly no expert on web development, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only explanation I have is that either your server crashes before the SDK is initialized, or there are "higher forces" preventing the event from being sent (e.g. process being killed with SIGKILL)

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is there any way to determine if this is the case? I currently have a free account, so I can't submit a ticket and I'm not about to pay for something which might not work.

Comment: Do you have access to server logs? The SDK can print out additional information about each error it captures when you call `init` with `debug=True`

Comment: Unfortunately, the logs didn't tell me anything informative. Given that we need server space for other projects, we've decided to host the project elsewhere.